# React - Manage conditionnal rendering with state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, use-state

I'm stuck with a rendering problem. I have a modal form to create/edit an entity (stored in the parent state list), I render a list of "cards" corresponding to each entity in the list. On each card there is a button opening a modal form to edit the entity. The problem is, I can't re-render my form according to the current action (add / edit) and current object.

As the problem is complex to explain, I've reproduced it : https://codesandbox.io/s/myzoo-cbpw8?file=/index.js:2688-2711

Once I've created an entity I'm stuck with the edit form, I cannot re-render a new form. It would imply rendering a new form then set the visibility state to true and that's not working.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this ?

If you have any tips or best practice about my codesandbox, let me know !

Comment: How about resetting the form after submit?

Comment: I saw that you used resetFields() in the onSubmit handler. Have you tried to use controlled inputs? (store their value in the react state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to manage both editing and adding dialogs with a single visibility variable, so when you open adding dialog, it opens editing dialogs too.

I think maybe it's better to render a single dialog,both for editing and adding, and store in a variable the animal you want to edit after opening the dialog, or storing false/null in case you want to create a new animal.

[Link to example](https://codesandbox.io/s/myzoo-forked-b93ye)

Comment: That's right ! Managing both states with a single function (hideFormAndUpdateList) is really convenient.
How can I get ride of the "Cannot update during an existing state transition" warning on the first render of AnimalCard ?

Comment: @lucas24007 I updated the example to fix that issue. That error is produced when you try to modify the component state while rendering it. You can solve that using useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue(animal);
  }, [animal]); so values in animal variable are set to form when they change. I also splited the code in several components so it's easier to read

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example here https://codesandbox.io/s/myzoo-forked-7t9em?file=/index.js:177-198. I think the problem was the same state `isVisible` was managing the 2 forms.

So when you open any of the forms, the component AnimalForm is called with `add` action then with `edit` action. We need to have it called in just one case.

So, I just made a small change and have a variable `isVisible` for each form. This way the forms are opened independently.